# How to get UUID for VirtualDisk in vSphere 5.5 java api?

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

In virtualDisk object I can find diskObjectId, which is durable and unmutable identifier (according to VMware docs: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fvim.vm.device.VirtualDisk.html). But if I detach the virtual hard disk and attach it again to instance then also diskObjectId for that virtual hard disk remains same as before detaching. Eg, diskObjectId was "2086-2001" and even after detaching hard disk, I created a new hard disk and same diskObjectId("2086-2001") got assigned to it.

I want to identify virtual hard disk with unique identifier (uuid). How can I get uuid for Virtual Disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualDisk object has 2 identifiers ([vmware documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/converter-sdk/conv55_apireference/vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk.html)):

- diskObjectId : Virtual disk durable and unmutable identifier. Virtual disk has a UUID field but that can be set through VirtualDiskManager APIs. This identifier is a universally unique identifier which is not settable. VirtualDisk can remain in existence even if it is not associated with VM.
- uuid

But I prefer using 'diskObjectId' because of the reason mentioned above.

I am getting unique identifier by below mentioned way :

```
    VirtualMachineConfigInfo vmConfig = vm.getConfig();
    VirtualDevice[] vds = vmConfig.getHardware().getDevice();
    for(VirtualDevice vd : vds){
        if(vd instanceof VirtualDisk){
            System.out.println(vd.getDiskObjectId());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I am fetching Hard Disk Details

First get all Devices of your VM

```
     VirtualDevice[] device=vm.getConfig().getHardware().getDevice();
```

Then Find HardDisk in fetched Devices, Find their Backing Info and Fetch UUID from there

Sample Code

```
VirtualDevice[] device=vm.getConfig().getHardware().getDevice();



        for (VirtualDevice disk : device)
        {
            if(disk.getDeviceInfo().getLabel().contains("Hard disk"))
            {
                 VirtualDiskFlatVer2BackingInfo backing = (VirtualDiskFlatVer2BackingInfo) disk.getBacking();
                System.out.println(backing.uuid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is always better to check if virtualDevice is instance of VirtualDisk class before getting uuid. Filtering virtualDisk from all virtualDevice based on label is not the right way to do it.                         
                `VirtualMachineConfigInfo vmConfig = vm.getConfig();
  VirtualDevice[] vds = vmConfig.getHardware().getDevice();
  for(VirtualDevice vd : vds){
   if(vd instanceof VirtualDisk){
    System.out.println(vd.getDiskObjectId());
   }
  }`